# Moving multiple files in R using loop

Tags: r

I know there were some questions very similar to mine, but I have different and strange problem.

I am working on a script which will archive files from one location to another.
The problem is, R is not moving the files when I use file.rename() for multiple files in a loop or if I try to use it in 1 line with vector of old paths and vector of new paths.
E.g.

```
for (i in 1:length(old_files_all)) {
  try(file.rename(from = file.path(old_files_all[i]), to = file.path(new_paths[i])))
  #or without try/file.path inside of method ^
}
```

Such loop doesn't move file but when I run code manually for each position of the loop like:

```
try(file.rename(from = file.path(old_files_all[1]), to = file.path(new_paths[1])))
```

It works....

Could you guys help me, how to solve this 'issue'.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) You don't need `file.path`. 2) `file.rename` is vectorized, you don't need the loop. 3) Are `new_paths` directories or file names?

Comment: @RuiBarradas
1) This is right, I know. Shouldn't involve it here
2) I know it, tried as well without a loop
3) Both, old and new paths are full paths to the files (it is being created during prior code of script)

Answer (score 0):

you can use file.rename with vectors directly without a loop.

```
#create some example files
file.create(paste0("test", formatC(1:10, width = 2, flag = "0"), ".txt"))
#create vectors with old and new file names
files_old <- list.files(pattern = "^test[0-9]{2}\\.txt", getwd())
files_new <- paste0(getwd(), "//Delete//", files_old)

#move files
file.rename(from = files_old, to = files_new)
```

Comment: Yes I agree and I admit I have tried without a loop. It still doesn't work for me.
Both, files_old and files_new are full paths to the files.
When I try try(file.rename(from = files_old, to = files_new)) I get all FALSEs and when I do it manually it works properly. 

Those are server locations, but I have full access

Comment: Hi @Rafal you have address the file with full path and filename. Otherwise I think it is some issues with your permissions. Does the example above work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works for example above. It might be issue with permissions you are right. Thank you for your help! Cheers